# ExtJs 4.2 example build

Tags: extjs4.2

I am new to ExtJs.

- When practicing in eclipse do we need to include the entire library(52 MB approx) in the appropriate location?
- Is there any shorter version of this library?
- Can I delete some files in the library which are not important?
- What are the necessary .js files to be included for building a sample MVC pattern, CRUD operation support application in ExtJs 4.2?

Answer (score 1):

For my setup, I include the `/ext` directory in my project, however I exclude it from the build path so that it doesn't slow Eclipse down.  See [Eclipse: Javascript validation disabled. but still generating errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102299/eclipse-javascript-validation-disabled-but-still-generating-errors)

Then, if you don't even want to see the directory in your workspace, you can [create a working set](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cworkset.htm).

I wouldn't recommend deleting/excluding ExtJS source files from your project, especially if you are using Sencha Cmd and/or using dynamic loading in your application.

If you really want to include the bare-minimum, you could get away with using `ext-all.js`, `ext-all.css`, and making sure you have all of the ExtJS image files.