# Angular Js in Eclipse

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, angularjs

I want to use `angular.js` in my project. I currently use JSF as a framework in my project.
I use Eclipse as IDE.

While trying to use `angular.js` in my project, I found an error of `Invalidformalparameter`
in `angular.js`. I also found many syntactical errors in `jquery.js`, `jquery.min.js` and `angular.js`.

Please help me.

Attachments:

- [Screenshot of IDE showing errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b39pv.jpg)

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282448/change-eclipse-settings-to-ignore-errors-on-a-specific-file

Answer (score 0):

Don't take care of raported possible errors in public well-tested scripts. Just link it with `script` in your HTML.

Eventually turn of eclipse notification for this specific file.

Comment: I have unchecked the "javascript validator" in builders propery of my project but i am still unable to get the desired output with angular js. I didn't getting any error while executing my html page but it does not show the desired output. It seems that it is unable to use the angular.js file. It just shows the result as a simple html file would have shown.

Answer (score 0):

**angularjs-eclipse** by Angello  https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse addreses many issues or working with AngularJS in Eclipse.

[image]

[image]

I am co-author of [Nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/) and Enide Studio, and we are working with Angelo (author of angularjs-eclipse) on including that plugin into [Enide Studio](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/studio/2014/). Also guys from JBoss expressed desire to include this plugin into JBoss Developer Studio, ref [#28](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/issues/28)