# Eclipse not understanding jquery

Tags: jquery, eclipse, compiler-errors

I have a project that uses jquery. However, Eclipse thinks that there are errors in the completely unmodified file that I downloaded straight from the jquery website. Along with simply re-downloading a new jquery js file, I've tried everything in the below thread.

[Change Eclipse settings to ignore errors on a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282448/change-eclipse-settings-to-ignore-errors-on-a-specific-file)

Any other suggestions?

Comment: ctrl+a, ctrl+i, ctrl+s

Comment: I'm not sure what that is supposed to do, Jane Doh.

Comment: it should reindent the code.

Answer (score 0):

I use Aptana (built on Elipse) for this because it has code hinting for jQuery.

Comment: The problem isn't my code, the problem is that Eclipse thinks that there are javaScript errors in the actual jquery.js file itself.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery often leaves terminal `;` off lines since they can be optional.  Eclipse doesn't consider them optional and will always report them. It's annoying, but unless you're getting "red" errors from Eclipse, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting red errors from eclipse and can't run my project.

Comment: @user1424324: Can you identify what Eclipse is complaining about? Does it fall into a particular class of error?

Comment: It's saying there should be a bunch of semicolons in there.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript Validator only reports problems for .js files in Source folders, as mentioned in the linked question.  You can have it ignore jQuery as source that way.  If you do still want it to process jQuery, put it in a folder specified on the Libraries tab of the JavaScript Include Path property page.  Content Assist will then make of it what it can without the JavaScript Validator builder recording problems for the file.