# eclipse maven pom.xml <packaging> tag error

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, tycho

I wanted to build something different depending on the situation by allowing you to receive parameters in the  tag of maven.
There is no problem with the build of maven.
However, Eclipse displays an error warning.

[image]

[image]

I will also share the pom.xml setup file.

```
<packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>
<profiles>
<profile>
    <id>desktop</id>
    <properties>
        <packaging.type>eclipse-plugin</packaging.type>
    </properties>
</profile>

<profile>
    <id>console</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>consoleBuild</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    
    <properties>
        <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
    </properties>
 </profile>
 </profiles>
```

Can I turn off the warning?

I have tried the eclipse settings

1. Go to Window > Preferences > Validation and uncheck the manual and build for: XML Schema Validator, XML Validator
2. Right-click on the project, select Properties > Validation and uncheck the manual and build for: XML Schema Validator, XML Validator

But the warning is displayed as it is...

I checked all Maven settings on Eclipse.
Is it never possible to ignore this warning?

IDEA seems to ignore alerts using tags such as [<! – @startIgnoreUnknownXML –> ... <! – @endIgnoreUnknownXML –>](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181199/Feature-request-suppress-warnings-for-maven-pom.xml-files-in-editor.) but Eclipse doesn't have this option?

Please advise if there is a better way other than what I thought. Thank you.

Comment: Remove the property in packaging... why do you need that? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: Depending on the situation, we need to package the eclipse-plugin and jar.

Comment: That means you should have a multi module build where one is the jar and one is the eclipse plugin because configuration etc. is different...

Comment: An `eclipse-plugin` will be built as a JAR, so why do you need the package type `jar` in addition? And with POM-less Tycho you do not even require a `pom.xml` file.

Comment: This is a Maven-specific message, so try looking for Maven-specific preferences.

Comment: With the same code, once we create a program with UI applied using tycho, and once we package it into jar to create a console program.
If you set the console program to `eclipse-plugin`and then package it, a warning will appear that the dependency cannot be found and the modules will not be packaged. Is it wrong to package parameters differently depending on the situation in the above way?

Comment: I made it by referring to this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15134587/20620291

Comment: The desktop profile is built using tycho-compiler-plugin. The console is being built using the maven-compiler-plugin. Are the jar files generated for each one the same?? With the console profile, modules are built as jars and then combined into one jar.
Is there any information that can confirm whether the jars created by tycho and maven are the same?
Even if I search all day, I can't figure it out.
I would appreciate it if you could let me know what I am lacking.

Comment: Is there really no way to turn off maven validation on Eclipse?
I kept trying to work on it, tried all the ways I found it, but the error lingers.
Is it impossible because Eclipse doesn't support it?
If I'm doing anything wrong, any advice would be appreciated. I need help now..
I will share some of the many methods I have tried.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282448
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495378
https://ralph.blog.imixs.com/2017/04/26/eclipse-avoid-validation-of-maven-target-folders/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify your `packaging.type` property also at the top level to avoid this warning (the value set in the profile will override the value set at the top level):

```
<properties>
    <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
</properties>
<packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>
```

Better do not build the artifacts twice. Instead, publish/install the Eclipse plugin you built to your local Maven repository or [deploy it to a remote Maven repository](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho:How_to_deploy_to_a_Maven_repository), from which you can then use the same JAR as a regular Maven dependency.

Comment: Does this mean that after saving the file packaged with eclipse-plugin using tycho in the repository, you should import and use the saved file when packaging the Maven jar?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. With [`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) you can add any JAR to your local Maven repository and then it can be consumed as a regular Maven dependency.

Comment: Thank you so much for your interest and response to my problem.
Let me ask you one last question.
Can Eclipse be set to ignore maven pom.xml validation?
The build with maven works normally, but there is a problem due to an error warning in Eclipse.

Comment: Some Maven errors and warnings can be configured in the preferences _Maven > Errors/Warnings_ to not be displayed. In contrast, a _project build error_ indicates that something is preventing the project from being (incrementally) built, so it cannot be ignored. But there is certainly a solution for that. If you get stuck, ask a separate question with a [complete, but minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you again for your interest.
Thanks to your kind reply, I am solving the problem little by little.